# Extend an R function

Tags: r, function

I want to extend `setwd` trivially in R. Let's say `dir1` contains `dir2`. I write the following and run it.

```
Swd <- function(directory){
         setwd("directory") 
}
```

While my current working directory is `dir1`, I call `Swd(dir2)` but R throws the error message

```
Error in setwd("directory") : cannot change working directory
```

I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Use `setwd(directory)` instead of `setwd("directory")`. (Unless you really do want to invariably set the working directory to a local directory *named* `"directory"`!)

Comment: How is your function different from `setwd('dir2')` ? And are you aware that unless `dir2` contains the character string naming the subdirectory it won't work even with Josh's suggestion?

Comment: I understand now. Thanks Josh and Carl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, setwd() can fail if you don't have administrative privileges in R. In can also fail if the command is invalid as above.

It might be better to use the whole path for the directory parameter name. For instance, if the current directory is "~/Documents/R/dir1" and you want to change to "~/Documents/R/dir1/dir2" then use setwd("~/Documents/R/dir1/dir2").

Another possibility would be to use the getwd() directory function. Then you could use

```
Swd <- function(directory) {
    setwd( paste(getwd(),directory,sep="") )
}
```

where the directory parameter could equal to "/dir2" for instance and paste is used for string concatenation.

setwd("directory") doesn't work because "directory" is not a valid path. if you are on linux, try setwd("~/Documents") and see what happens, or on windows use setwd("C:/Users//Documents")

Comment: Or you may use `file.path`.